# Publishing Remotely To Wordpress?

Tags: remote

Hey i know that there are options to post to a wordpress blog remotely by email or by another source.

My blog is self hosted.

What other ways is there to publish besides via email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Built in to the current version of Wordpress there is "Remote Publishing" settings for Atom or XML-RPC, but that is geared towards programs that help you blog outside of your Wordpress control panel. You can configure it in the Settings > Writing area of your site's Wordpress dashboard.

If you want to publish the content of an RSS feed to your Wordpress site, you will need a "re-feeding" plugin such as FeedWordPress: http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/

Maybe you were thinking of publishing remotely as in a mobile app? Email is still probably the best route, but there are probably blogging apps, and they might need the Atom / XML-RPC setup to work with your site.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows you could of course post to WordPress self hosted using windows [live writer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-live/essentials-other-programs) which is part of the free [windows live essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows-live/essentials-other-programs) suite.

You would need to enable  XML-RPC in settings under writing > remote publishing. For more info see http://en.wordpress.com/windows-live-writer/

Answer (score 0):

You can publish via mobile phone, I guess you will find different solutions if you google it. I personally use [Woothemes](http://www.woothemes.com), and they have a plugin called WooTumblog and a  Iphone/Android App called Express, and then you can post notes, images, links and quotes directly from your phone. I find this very useful for blogging in the field!

More information [here!](http://www.woothemes.com/support/wootumblog/)

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting way is using the [JSON API plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api)'s `create_post` function. It uses nonces for authentication.